# Is it possible to post and later get post body in SoapUI?

Tags: java, groovy, service, mocking, soapui

At my project we mock certain data within SoapUi and use those mocks as responses from various external services when handling business logic in our project. We also have a separate test project where we instigate test scenarios.
What I would like to is to be able to post specific data to one of my mock services that then use the post body as a response when being called from the main project.

An example would be that from the test project I start a test that sends in a customers name ‘Alexander’ with ID X. Further on i the test that instigates the main project to ask SoapUI for the the name of person X. SoapUI responds with ‘Alexander’.

Comment: Sound like you might need a custom proxy. Or maybe a service-virtualization tool like Mountebank: http://www.mbtest.org/docs/mentalModel

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. :)
It sounds to me, you are placing yourself between two chairs. You want some sort of "CreateCustomer" or "UpdateCustomer" service to set the details of a customer, and then later on be able to get that very data through some "GetCustomer" service.
Thereby you are introducing another source for potential bugs. It seems like you are - sort of - end to end testing, but in a partially mocked environment. I think you would probably be better off splitting up the tests.
I think what you want to do is possible. I'm just not sure it is a good idea.